# How to change powerpoint pictures in widescreen format

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010

Hi I'am a Newbee in the world of PowerPoint VBA and hope my english is not too bad: I have to solve the following problem in PowerPoint 2010: First I change into the 16:9 widescreen format, then I go through to every picture which are now too big and change with size-dialog box from the picture only by clicking the up and down arrow for scaling height. The picture will be in the right form which I used before in the 4:3 presentation. That is easy but not if you have to change more then 100 of pictures. I tried so many times but nothing works. Here is my code:

```
Sub ChangePictures()
Dim sld As Slide
Dim sh As Shape
Dim meinShHeight As Double

ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideSize = 15

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
For Each sh In sld.Shapes
'If sh = msoLinkedOLEObject Or msoTextBox Then
        If sh.Type = msoPicture Then
'meinShHeight = sh.ScaleHeight.Value
'sh.ScaleHeight meinShHeight, msoScaleFromTopLeft
             sh.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
              With tSlide.Shapes.Select
                  .Height = ActiveWindow.Presentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight
                  .Width = ActiveWindow.Presentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth
             End With
'sh.ScaleHeight  1.75, msoTrue
'sh.ScaleHeight -1.75, msoTrue
        End If
'End If
  Next
Next

End Sub
```

Perhaps it is impossible to use this up and down arrow trick in VBA?
Unfortunately I cannot use PowerPoint 2013 then I didn't have any problem with my presentation.

Is there anybody who can help me. I hope to express my problem in the right way ;-)

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Kiki

Comment: Didn't `sh.ScaleHeight ActiveWindow.Presentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight, msoTrue` help?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
Sub ChangePictures()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim sh As Shape

    ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideSize = 15

    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each sh In sld.Shapes
            If sh.Type = msoPicture Then
                With sh
                    .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                    .ScaleHeight ActiveWindow.Presentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight, msoTrue
                    .ScaleWidth ActiveWindow.Presentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth, msoTrue
                End With
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Siddharth, thank you very much for this quick response. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. The presentation was changed correctly, but the picture disappeared and I got a big green slide. Do you know what has happend? Thank you in advanced Kiki

Comment: `and I got a big green slide` Green is usually associated with paranormal activity? Did you show your presentation to a paranormal expert :D Ok jokes apart. Would it be possible for me to see your presentation. Let me check it for you? If yes then upload it in www.wikisend.com and share the link here.

Comment: so today I have to work but tomorrow I will send my presentation to you. It is only one slide with a great picture of mine in order to look what has happend with one picture before I do this with 100 of pictures. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `with a great picture of mine` Then I am sure it is really haunted :P Anyways, will wait for your link.

Comment: Hello Siddharth, I don't know the plattform  wikisend  but I upload my PowerPoint presentation. I got this URL http://www.wikisend.com/download/397990/ but if I try to look at I've got a blanc site. So, do you know if I have to wait a little bit longer? Use this link and then tell me if you got the file. kiki

Comment: I've got it :-) I have to wait. The URL come by mail. I hope soon.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't receive any URL until now, so I use the Dropbox. This is the new URL: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hhsmnvvxz9i51c1/Trainerin.pptm. Please have a look at my presentation and use your code then we will see if you find the right solution. Thanks in advance. Kiki